# Is it possible to update a cell with the date another cell (or even better row) was modified WITHOUT the use of scripts?

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to update a cell with the date another cell (or even better row) was modified WITHOUT the use of scripts?

I have found several solutions to do this using a script but ideally, we wouldn't need to run off a script each time and the cells would auto-update

Answer (score 0):

yes you can but with a major disadvantage - the date will recalculate on every cell change you make or on every sheet opening. you can try in B1:

```
=IF(A1<>"", TODAY(), )
```

type in something in A1 > date in B1 will popup > tomorrow you open the sheet or change any cell in it and date will reupdate too